# Very long Newton cradle as a comparision to the invariance of the speed of light regarding the movement of the source?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, causality

If we place a Newton cradle 1 km long along the road and now passing on a bicycle hit the first element (sphere) with a hand the speed of the disturbance would be the same no matter how fast the bicycle is moving so the last element will move after the same time interval. Can this be compared with the phenomena of invariance of the speed of light regarding the movement of a source?

Comment: This would have been relatable had you been carrying the cradle with you and the disturbance still had the same velocity.

Comment: @AbsoluteZero... in that case the speed of the disturbance would be added to the velocity of the source which in the case of light would be c+v which is not  what has been measured for light...

Answer (score 0):

The force of the impact will travel the steel balls of the Newton cradle at the steel's speed of sound. The force of impact on the first ball is proportional to the force applied to the last ball, minus friction and kinetic losses in transmission.